# Google maps API : Finding the shortest Path

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello Guys I hope that you are well !

i'm developping an android App for delivery system ;

i'd like to know if there is a ready library or a way to know  what's the

shortest path to drive thru all the locations .

for example :

the driver has to fetch objects that are located in :(A,B,C,D)=>Locations

1. A(lat,long)
2. B(lat,long)
3. C(lat,long)
4. D(lat,long)

the app shows the driver what's the shortest path to take : 
Dloc(lat,long) = (Driver's Location)
the shortest path for example :

1. Dloc(to)A
   then
2. A(to)C
   then
3. C(to)B
   then
4. B(to)D

like the Djikstra's Shortest Path Algorithm does (Graph Theory).
i hope you guys understand my question

Comment: A good start is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

Comment: Google for The travelling salesman problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the google map direction API, it will give you the shortest path to travel all sites as well as add ur origin and destination and add your other locations with the waypoint will give you optimised path and live traffic update..